# ¿Cómo llamar a una función a través de un evento de un elemento HTML cargado dinámicamente?

Tags: javascript, html5, eventos, onclick

Tengo una tabla HTML la cual se carga con uno datos traídos en formato JSON. Too bien hasta ahí pues la tabla carga todos los dato perfectamente.
Dentro de esta tabla debo tener un botón de eliminar, el cual debe eliminar de la tabla al elemento seleccionado.
Tengo un botón cuyo atributo `value` es igual al id del elemento que está siendo impreso. El problema está en este botón, pues cada vez que intento llamar a la función que maneja el evento de eliminación, la consola me salta el error de `function undefined` cuando la función sí existe.
He probado definiendo la función dentro de la etiqueta `script` que tengo en el archivo HTML y también llamando a la misma desde un archivo .js externo, y ninguna de las dos maneras me ha funcionado.
Dejo parte del código para su revisión.

**AQUÍ ES DONDE IMPRIMO LOS DATOS DEL JSON**

```
html += `<tr class="py-4">
                    <td class="border border-radius-20 text-center" id='containerIMG'>
                        <img src='${ filter[i][0].img }' />
                    </td>
                    <td style="min-width: 160px">
                        <strong id='pre-alert-code' class="d-flex align-items-center">
                            <i class="fas fa-plane mr-2"></i>
                            ${ filter[i][0].code }
                        </strong>
                        <p class="text-gray mb-0 pt-3" style="font-size: 10px;">
                            <a href="" class="text-gray d-block" style='text-decoration: underline;'>Ver descripción</a>
                        </p>
                        <span class="text-gray mt-2 d-block">
                            <strong class="text-dark">Fecha de ingreso: </strong>${ filter[i][0].inDate }
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="px-0" style='min-width: 50px'>
                        <div class="form-check w-100">
                            <button class="btn" type='button' onClick='deleteItem()' value='${ filter[i][0].id }'>
                                <img src="./resources/eliminar.svg">
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>`
```

**ESTA ES LA FUNCIÓN QUE DEBERÍA LLAMARSE AL HACER CLICK EN EL BOTÓN DE ELIMINAR**

```
function deleteItem(){

    console.log('Hola');

}
```

Comment: Prueba  `onclick` en lugar de `onClick`

Comment: Por alguna razón esto sí funcionó. Muchísimas gracias.